# how can i push first and refresh the page in vue router?

Tags: vue.js

hello guys I'm having trouble on how can i push first and to refresh to that push page.

what is happening in my code is like this.

```
 let logOuts = () => {
    logOut();

    router.push('/home');
    router.go();
  };
```

for example:
when user `logOut` they will be back to the `/home` and the `home page` will refresh

however it's not going the way i want it to be.
`when the function is click` it pushes to `/home`

but when the `router.go()` refresh execute it refreshes but goes back to the page before the `router.push(/home)` or the page before the homepage.

so I'm wondering how can i achieve pushing to `/home` and then refresh the `/home page`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for the vue-router to finish pushing and then reload the window

```js
router.push(`/home`).then(() => {
    window.location.reload()
  })
```

Comment: i thought using window.location.reload is a bad practice in vue. that is why i'm using built in navigation which is vue router. is that true?

Comment: @MikaelTenshio Yes and No. The best practice is only good when it is put in the right context. In your situation, you want to refresh the page, which breaks the normal behavior of a SPA. Anyway, when you refresh the page, everything will be loaded from the initial state. So you can choose what method you want